# TextView failure

Tags: android, textview, set

I'm programming my  first android app.
I want to set text on a `TextView`. 
(I already searched here and found out, how to do it...But it  still don't work)

Do you know, what the problem is?

This is my Java code.

```
package com.example.randomcraps;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.layout.number);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void getRandomNumber(){
        int i;
        double savePoint;
        savePoint = Math.random();
        savePoint = savePoint*100+1;
        i = (int)savePoint;
        text.setText(i);
    }

}
```

This is my XML Code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:text="@string/Button1"
        android:onClick="getRandomNumber" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/RandomNumber" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to

```
TextView text;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number); // id of textview in activity_main.xml
 }
```

`findViewById` looks for a view with the id mentioned in the current inflated layout. So you need to set layout to the activity and then initialize your views.

Also change

```
text.setText(i); 
// looks for a resource with the id mentioned if not found you get ResourceNotFoundException
```

To

```
text.setText(String.valueOf(i)); 
// int i; i is an int value. Use String.valueOf(intvalue)
```

Edit:

Your method signature is different. It should be

```
public void getRandomNumber(View V){ // missing View as param
        ... //rest of the code
    }
```

Coz you have

```
android:onClick="getRandomNumber"
```

Quoting from docs

```
public static final int onClick
```

Name of the method in this View's context to invoke when the view is clicked. This name must **correspond to a public method that takes exactly one parameter of type View. For instance, if you specify android:onClick="sayHello", you must declare a public void sayHello(View v) method of your context (typically, your Activity)**.

Comment: `findViewById()` won't find anything `R.layout`, should be `R.id`. Otherwise this is good advice.

Comment: @laalto you are right just failed to spot it. will edit now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this.

```
TextView text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);
}
```

Also

```
text.setText(String.valueOf(i));
```

**NOTE:** findViewByID finds view from content. So basically you have to use that method after you set your content.

Comment: I tried this right befor, but the the ID is still underlined. I don't know why, but "number" is still underlined. And it says: "Number is not resolved or is not a field.

Comment: Have you declared a textView with id number at your activity_main?

Comment: Ok I've edited my answer. Use R.id.number not R.layout.number.

Comment: @Infinit666 you still have some mistakes in your code check my post

Answer (score 0):

Set text color after setText and for guarantee set the font size. Sometimes it makes the color default white.